# Removing JSON value that contains certain word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, regex, parsing

I'm using a [large API](http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule/full) that contains a JSON file of TV Show information.

The key 'name' contains guest information. Most of them return with the list of guests, however some return as 'Episode [x]'. For example:

```
for (x in data){
 let title = data[x]._embedded.show.name;
 let guests = data[x].name;
 let airdate = data[x].airdate;

 switch(title){
   // ...
   case 'The Daily Show with Trevor Noah':
      p.innerHTML = airdate + " " + guests;
      noah.appendChild(p);
      console.log(airdate, guests);
      break;
   default:
      break;
 }
}
```

Guest values return as:

Kevin Young, Antoinette Robertson, Gen. Michael Hayden, David Blaine, Episode 63, Episode 64, Episode 65

I'd like to display just the names, and somehow remove any instance of 'Episode'. I have a few ideas, but I'm new to JavaScript and having some trouble. If more code is necessary to answer this question, I'll update this question. Thanks in advance

Comment: `If code is necessary to answer this question, I'll update this with necessary information.` Yes, always post the code you've tried with your question if you want help debugging it.

Comment: Sure thing, I just updated my question

Comment: I don't think that a `switch(title){` is returned by a JSON call... Rather a valid JSON.

Comment: take a look at [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function

Comment: @AmrAly Replacing does remove 'Episode' but I want to remove the entire value that contains 'Episode'. Otherwise, the episode numbers still exist. Wondering if there's some sort of 'contains' method that will remove all instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to only print out items that don't have `episode` in the title, you could put an `if()` statement before your `switch()`, and then use a [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statement if you come across an invalid item to skip it (`continue` will tell Javascript to basically skip to the next item).

```
for (x in data){
  let title = data[x]._embedded.show.name;
  let guests = data[x].name;
  let airdate = data[x].airdate;

  if (guests.substr(0, 7) === 'Episode') continue;
  // if the title starts with "Episode", no code after this line will be run for this item

  switch(title){
    // ...
    case 'The Daily Show with Trevor Noah':
      p.innerHTML = airdate + " " + guests;
      noah.appendChild(p);
      console.log(airdate, guests);
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. If statement should start with 'guests' rather than 'title', but this does work.

Answer (score 1):

How about using regex?

```
var pattern = /(,\s)?Episode\s\d+((,\s)?)/g;
var guests = data[x].name.replace(pattern, "");
```

Test cases:

```
var str1 = "Kevin Young, Antoinette Robertson, Gen. Michael Hayden, David Blaine, Episode 63, Episode 64, Episode 65"; 
var str2 = "Episode 63, Episode 64, Episode 65, Kevin Young, Antoinette Robertson, Gen. Michael Hayden, David Blaine"; 
var str3 = "Kevin Young, Antoinette Robertson, Gen. Michael Hayden, David Blaine";
var str4 = "Episode 63, Episode 64, Antoinette Robertson, Episode 65";
var str5 = "Episode 63, Episode 64, Episode 65";
var str6 = "Episode 63";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the instances of `Episode [0-9]` like so:

```js
var str = "Kevin Young, Antoinette Robertson, Gen. Michael Hayden, David Blaine, Episode 63, Episode 64, Episode 65";

var newStr = str.replace(/,[ ]?Episode[ ]?[0-9]+/g, '');

console.log(newStr);

// Kevin Young, Antoinette Robertson, Gen. Michael Hayden, David Blaine
```